# Android Studio Xml Design Greyed Out

Tags: android-studio

Hi I have switched to a new PC and downloaded Android Studio. The design preview of Xml files were fine at first but after I added a device it started to grey out in a couple of seconds and this only happens to my main xml file.

[Here is the main xml preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTJAz.png)

[How I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8YJv.png)

I tried changing API levels and the device didn't do much for me. I also tried changing theme to Light Mode

Answer (score 0):

try to unistall and reinstall android studio.
it seems an IDE bug.